# Stop Debug Statements from publishing in log

Tags: java, linux, logging, log4j2

I have the following log.properties file in my Java project:

```
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level= INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=[%1$tF %1$tT] [%4$s] %5$s %n
```

I am declaring the Logger as follows in one file which generates most of the log:

```
public static final Logger  logger = LogManager.getLogger();
```

The log4j2.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval ="5">
        <Properties>
                <Property name="log-path">${LOGDIR}</Property>
        </Properties>
        <Appenders>
                <RollingFile name="RollingFile"
                        fileName="workerApplication.log"
                        filePattern="workerApplication-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
                        <PatternLayout>
                                <Pattern>%d %p %c [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
                        </PatternLayout>
                        <Policies>
                                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20 MB" />
                        </Policies>
                        <!-- <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="4" /> -->
                </RollingFile>
        </Appenders>
        <Loggers>
                <Logger name="root" level="warn" additivity="false">
                        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
                </Logger>
                <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
                        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
                </Root>
        </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

In my workerApplication.log, I am still getting the debug statements too that are in my code. I only want INFO and above level. I have changed in both places the level of the log but it is not working. Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong? The project is being deployed as an RPM in Linux

Comment: Try changing line <Root level="debug" additivity="false"> to <Root level="info" additivity="false">

Answer (score 0):

You set the loglevel for each logger in log4j2.xml. Since you only have one logger you can change the loglevel for that logger to only get logging for level `info` and higher.

Please change

```
<Root level="debug" additivity="false">
   <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
</Root>
```

to

```
<Root level="info" additivity="false">
   <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
</Root>
```